# Make a jquery function wait till it's previous call has been resolved

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

So, I've searched for this high and low and maybe I'm just having trouble understanding jQuery's deferred function or I'm completely on the wrong track. So any help would be appreciated folks!

I basically have a custom jQuery function `messager` that displays a message with a `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`.

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.messager = function(message, effect, speed) {

        $(this).fadeOut(speed).delay(speed).text(message).fadeIn(speed);

        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

So, I have a div called `$elem` and when `$elem.messager` gets called multiple times (with different messages), I would like the messager function to wait till its last call has finished. As in the last `FadeIn` has finished. Because currently what's happening is that the second call of the function is overwriting the animation effect of the first call of the function.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't make it wait.  You have to use a callback that can be passed in to messager and then called when the last `fadeOut()` is done.  Or you could use promises (which also end up using callbacks)

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. That's what I'm trying to figure out. How do I pass the callback from the function to itself...? As in, what will be passed to the messager the first time it is called?

Also, can't wrap my head around promise().

Answer (score 1):

### jQuery Deferred Way

jQuery Deferred object (roughly compromising CommonJS Promises API) can help us managing queued operations. Here is my implementation of queuing messages. You can pass through multiple messages as an array in one call, or synchronize different message boards easily because #messager() returns jQuery object itself but also wrapped as a promise object which will be resolved just when message(s) being displayed.

```js
(function ($) {
    function awaits($el) {
       var awaits = $el.data('_awaits');
       awaits || $el.data('_awaits', awaits = []);
       return awaits;
    }
  
    function resolveNext(curr /*, ignored */) {
       var head = awaits(this).shift();
       if (head === curr) {
           resolveNext.call(this, 'not await');
       } else {
           head && head.resolve();
       }
    }
  
    function display(message, speed) {
        var $self = this, await = $.Deferred(), willDone = $.Deferred();
        awaits($self).push(await) > 1 || await.resolve();
        
        await.done(function() {
            function reveal() {
               $self.text(message).fadeIn(speed, function() {
                   resolveNext.call($self, await);
                   willDone.resolve();
               });
            }

            $self.fadeOut(speed/2, reveal);
        });
        return willDone.promise(this);
    };

    $.fn.messager = function(message, speed) {
        speed = speed || 500;

        if ($.isArray(message)) {
            var arr = [];
            message.forEach(function(m) {
                arr.push(display.call(this, m, speed));
            }, this);
            return $.when.apply(this, arr);
        } else {
            return display.call(this, message, speed);
        }
    }

}( jQuery ));



function play() {
  $('#msgbox1').messager(['A demo of', 'queued messages'], 1000);
  for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--) $('#msgbox1').messager(i);
  $('#msgbox1').messager(['Ready to sing...', 'Singing...']);    
  
  for (var i = 8; i > 0; i--) $('#msgbox2').messager('***');    
  for (i = 1; i < 8; i++) $('#msgbox2').messager(String.fromCharCode(64 + i));
  
  $('#msgbox2')
      .messager('')
      .done(function() { 
          $('#msgbox1')
              .messager(['End of demo.', 'Thank you.', 'Run again?'], 1000)
              .done(function() {
                  $('#msgbox1, #msgbox2').one('click', play); 
                  $('#msgbox2').messager('>');
              });
      });
}

play();
```

```css
html {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
#msgbox1, #msgbox2 {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
  font-size: 36pt;
  text-align: center;
  height: 1.8em;
  cursor: default;
}
#msgbox2 {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Queuing Messages with jQuery Deferred Object</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="msgbox1"></div>
  <div id="msgbox2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit, Updated

Try

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.messager = messager;

    function messager(message, speed, callback) {

        var that = $(this);
        if (that.data("queue") === undefined) {
            $.fx.interval = 0;
            that.data("queue", []);
            that.data("msg", []);
        };
        var q = that.data("queue"),
            msgs = that.data("msg");
        q.push([message, speed, callback]);
        msgs.push(message);

        var fn = function (m, s, cb) {

            return that.fadeOut(s, function () {
                that.text(m)
            })
                .delay(s)
                .fadeIn(s, cb)
                .promise("fx")
                .done(function (el) {
                console.log("callback", q.length);

                if (q.length > 1) {
                    q.splice(0, 1);
                    fn.apply(el, q[0])
                } else {
                    el.data("queue", []);
                    console.log("done", el.data("queue").length);
                    always(promise, ["complete", msgs])
                        .then(complete);
                }
                return el.promise("fx");
            })
        }

        , promise = $.when(!that.queue("fx").length 
                               ? fn.apply(that, q[0]) 
                               : that.promise("fx"))

        , always = function (elem, args) {
            if (elem.state() === "pending") {
                console.log(elem.state(), args)
            } else {
                if (elem.state() === "resolved") {
                    elem.done(function (elem) {
                        console.log(msgs.length + " messages complete");
                    })
                };
            };
            return elem.promise("fx")
        };

        always(promise, ["start", message, q.length]);

        return that
    };
}(jQuery));
```

See [.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```js
(function ($) {

    $.fn.messager = messager;

    function messager(message, speed, callback) {
        
        var that = $(this);
        if (that.data("queue") === undefined) {
            $.fx.interval = 0;
            that.data("queue", []);
            that.data("msg", []);
        };
        var q = that.data("queue"),
            msgs = that.data("msg");
        q.push([message, speed, callback]);
        msgs.push(message);

        var fn = function (m, s, cb) {

            return that.fadeOut(s, function () {
                that.text(m)
            })
                .delay(s)
                .fadeIn(s, cb)
                .promise("fx")
                .done(function (el) {
                console.log("callback", q.length);

                if (q.length > 1) {
                    q.splice(0, 1);
                    fn.apply(el, q[0])
                } else {
                    el.data("queue", []);
                    console.log("done", el.data("queue").length);
                    always(promise, ["complete", msgs])
                        .then(complete);
                }
                return el.promise("fx");
            })
        }
        
        , promise = $.when(!that.queue("fx").length 
                               ? fn.apply(that, q[0]) 
                               : that.promise("fx"))

        , always = function (elem, args) {
            if (elem.state() === "pending") {
                console.log(elem.state(), args)
            } else {
                if (elem.state() === "resolved") {
                    elem.done(function (elem) {
                        console.log(msgs.length + " messages complete");
                    })
                };
            };
            return elem.promise("fx")
        };

        always(promise, ["start", message, q.length]);

        return that
    };
}(jQuery));

            var complete = function() {
                if (!$("pre").is("*")) {
                    $("body").append("<pre>" + JSON.stringify($(this).data("msg"), null, 4))
                } else {
                    $("pre")
                    .text(JSON.stringify($(this).data("msg"), null, 4));  
                    $("label[for=messages]").text("messages updated")
                    .show(0).delay(350).hide(0)
                };
            };
    
    var fx = function() {
        $(this).css("color", "purple").animate({
            fontSize: "72"
        }, 100, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                fontSize: "36"
            }, 100, function() {
                $(this).css("color", "inherit")
            })
        })
    };
    
    var input = $("input");
    
    var $elem = $("#messages");
    $elem.messager("0", 1000)
    
    .messager("1", 100)
    .messager("2", 200)
    .messager("3", 300)
    .messager("4", 400)
    .messager("5", 500)
    .messager("6", 600)
    .messager("7", 700)
    .messager("8", 800)
    .messager("9", 900);
    
    $.each("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split(""), function(key, val) {
        $elem.messager(val, 200, fx);
    });
    
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $elem.messager(input.val().length > 0 ? input.val() : $.now(), 200);
        input.val("")
    });
```

```css
#messages {
    display:block;
    height:38px;
    font-size:36px;
    position : absolute;
}

label[for=messages] {
    color:blue;
}

pre {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="button">add messages</label>&nbsp;<label for="messages"></label><br>
<input type="text" /><button>click</button>
<br />
<div id="messages">messages</div>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
(function ( $ ) {
$.fn.messager = function(message, effect, speed, gothru) {
    if (!$(this).data('message'))
    {
        $(this).data('message', Array());
    }
    $(this).data('message').push({messageContent: message, messageEffect: effect, messageSpeed: speed});
    if ($(this).data('message').length > 1 && gothru != true)
    {
        return;
    }
    $(this).fadeOut(speed).delay(speed).text(message).fadeIn(speed, function(){
        $(this).data("message").shift();
        if ($(this).data('message').length > 0)
        {
            var arrMessage = $(this).data('message');
            var messageContent = arrMessage[0].messageContent;
            var messageEffect= arrMessage[0].messageEffect;
            var messageSpeed= arrMessage[0].messageSpeed;
            $(this).data("message").shift();
            $(this).messager(messageContent , messageEffect, messageSpeed, true);
        }
    });
    return this;
};
}( jQuery ));
</script>
```

It's good now.

Comment: I'm sorry mate, where do you get `this.active` from? I can't see it in the documentation...

Comment: this.active is undefined at the first time. That means at the first time this.active will be assigned to value true.

Comment: Oh right, so it's not a standard javascript property like `this.length`?

Comment: Sorry dude. But I tried your solution and it just ended up in an infinite loop... :/

Answer (score 0):

### The naive way of doing it recursively:

Make a global variable(boolean), in this case called queue. If queue is false, set it to true and begin executing the code you want to run. When that code finishes, set queue back to false. Otherwise, if queue was true, just recursively call `_this.messager()` until queue is set back to false, which would mean that the code is finished running.

`fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` can take callbacks as the final argument, so I'm utilizing that here.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="messageBox"></div>
```

#### javaScript:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  var queue = false;

  $.fn.messager = function(message, effect, speed) {
    var _this = $(this);

    if (!queue) {
        queue = true;
        _this.fadeOut(speed, function() {
          _this.text(message);
          _this.fadeIn(speed, function() {
            queue = false;
          });
        });
    } else {
        _this.messager(message, effect, speed);
    }
    return this;
  };
}( jQuery ));
$('#messageBox').messager('One', 300);
$('#messageBox').messager('Two', 300);
$('#messageBox').messager('Three', 300);
```

This typically results in:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

---

### A more advanced example:

Here we create a second variable called counter to keep track of how many times 'messager' is called recursively and doesn't exceed the limit specified in the options. I set a default of 50, which can be overwritten by the options parameter.

In addition, we've separated out the code that you want to run. This could even be multiple functions that call each other, the important bit is making sure that when your code is finished running, you set queue to false rather than returning false and setting queue to the result of the function. Setting it to the result of the function just makes it undefined until the function finishes returning. We want it to remain as true until the code is finished executing.

This example also throttles the recursive calling so that it's only called once every 100 milliseconds, although that too can be overwritten with whatever value you like (in milliseconds) via the options parameter.

#### HTML:

```
<div id="messageBox"></div>
```

#### javaScript:

```
(function( $ ) {
  var queue = false;
  var counter = 0;

  $.fn.messager = function(message, effect, speed, options) {
    var _S = $.extend({
        throttle: 100,
        counter: 50
    }, options);
    var _this = $(this);

    counter += 1;

    function codeToRun() {
      _this.fadeOut(speed, function() {
        _this.text(message);
        _this.fadeIn(speed, function() {
          queue = false;
        });
      });
    }

    if (!queue) {
      queue = true;
      codeToRun();
      counter = 0;
    } else {
      if (counter < _S.counter) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          _this.messager(message, effect, speed);
        }, _S.throttle);
      }
    }
    return this;
  };
})( jQuery );
$('#messageBox').messager('One', 300);
$('#messageBox').messager('Two', 300);
$('#messageBox').messager('Three', 300);
```

---

For some reason, calling methods on `$(this)` directly gives me:

```
[Window, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, selector: "", toArray: function, get: function…]
```

But storing `$(this)` in a variable and calling methods on that variable gives me the correct element:

```
[div#messageBox, selector: "#messageBox", context: document, jquery: "1.11.0", constructor: function, toArray: function…]
```

Comment: Thanks @emilySmitley, but I tried your solution as one of my first attempts at solving this and you basically end up exhausting the stack pretty quickly - because, the `queue` variable is regenerated *everytime* the `messager` function is call because it is a custom jquery function...

Comment: the queue variable is outside of the messager function and is only created once. Besides, if it were inside the messager function, this example wouldn't even work. It'd get set to false every time `messager` gets called.

Comment: Hm, @emilysmitley, I was sure that it was created every time. Which is why I believe that the `else` condition is firing every time and hence giving the following error:
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: If this whole thing wasn't wrapped in an immediately invoked function expression, `queue` would be a global variable. Put `queue` inside the IIFE, not within `$.fn.messager`. Also, to avoid `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, see my latest update which includes limiting and throttling.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed advanced edit.
Unfortunately, while it resolves the `stack size` error, it doesn't solve the original problem. the `CodeToRun` is still getting called before the previous animation is finished...

Comment: I think I fixed that now. Forgot to have the function return false from within the callback for `fadeIn()`.

Comment: @sahil I just made another update. Tested it in codepen and it's working fine for me now - http://codepen.io/hellaFont/pen/NPKoWv?editors=001