# Patterns for handling the response of only the latest async request in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, debouncing

Have discovered a bug with respect to debounced input and handling responses.

I have a search input that queries the server as you type. I put a debounce on it set to 300ms. However, sometimes there's some odd behavior:

User types "ab", waits 300ms, types "c" before that first request resolves. In the search bar they see "abc", but there are now two network requests. Sometimes the second request ("abc") resolves first, then the first request ("ab") resolves and overwrites the results list. So the user sees a list of results for "ab", but the search input has "abc".

This seems like less of an issue of debounce per se, and more along the lines of finding a way to discard "old" promises so that they can be ignored when they resolve.

So for example - what I want

- *types `"ab"`*
- *send request "ab"*
- *types `"c"`*
- *send request "abc"*
- *"abc" returns response, handle promise resolution*
- *"ab" returns response, ignore promise*

Are there any common patterns/approaches for this sort of thing in Angular? It sounds like it would be a common issue.

E.g "Resolve only the latest promise that was created"?

Comment: can you provide your code?

Comment: It's indeed difficult to solve this problem with `Promises`. The problem you describe above is a perfect usecase to introduce `RxJS` into your application. With `RxJS` you have operators like `distinctUntilChanged()` and `switchMap()` to solve this problem.

Comment: You can create a queue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859275/make-a-jquery-function-wait-till-its-previous-call-has-been-resolved/. Though Question tagged `jquery` pattern is also reproducible using native `Promise`

Comment: @guest271314 that's a totally different usecase...

Comment: @Dieterg Try typing at input field at stacksnippets at linked Question. The results should be displayed in sequential order of input. The previous input could be removed from displayed results if new input occurs. From perspective here, not totally different; though could be incorrect in interpretation of Question

Comment: @guest271314 the fact is that it might be possible that one call goes to India and another call goes to America, in the promise chain there is just no reliable way to know which call you're resolving.

Comment: @Dieterg There should be a reliable way to determine which input was placed into queue array by referencing index of item within array. Use only last input for displayed results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109928/discussion-between-dieterg-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a perfect use-case to introduce `RxJS`, Angular 2 has default support for `RxJS`. However in Angular 1 it's also possible to use this library, take a look at the official `rx.angular.js` library over [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js/).

If you include this library you should be able to solve your problem as follows:

HML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
```

JS

```
observeOnScope($scope, 'search')
  .debounceTime(300)
  .distinctUntillChanged()
  .switchMap(search)
  .safeApply($scope, function (data) {
     $scope.data = data;
  })
  .subscribe();

function search() {
  return rx.Observable.fromPromise($http({ ... }));
}
```

**Edit: a more in depth article can be found over [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-introduction-to-reactive-extensions-rxjs-a86a7430a61f#.ybcoa0tyn)**

Comment: Unfortunately, adding new dependencies to the app I work on is a bit of a process, but after playing around with this, it's definitely the way to go. For the time being I decided to track the latest request using a random token which I bind to the success handler, and if the bound token does not match the current token, then just bail out of the handler. It works for now, but I'll be creating a technical debt to add and refactor to RxJS, as this is clearly the right way to go. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this simply using subscription.

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';  

export class Component  {
constructor(){}
    subscription: Subscription;

    getData() {
       // just check if subscription is already there then unsubscribe that 
        if (this.subscription) {
          this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }
        this.subscription = this._http.get(url).subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
          },
          error => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        )

      }
}
```