# Can I resolve a Promise from the outside?

Tags: promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Using ES2015, can I resolve a promise *from the outside* i.e. trigger a resolution after its creation?

Like

```
const promise = new Promise();
promise.then(() => foo());
promise.resolve(); // foo() gets executed
```

Comment: *After* does not necessarily relate to *outside*? In general, no, and there's no need to. Also a `promise.resolve` method would definitely be an antipattern.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Promises for promises that are yet to be created](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37426037/1048572)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
let resolvePromise = null;
const promise = new Promise(resolve => resolvePromise = resolve);
promise.then(foo => console.log(foo));
resolvePromise('bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure we can. just take the reference of the function outside and call it.
Since functions are object(which are stored as reference in variables) we can call resolve function from outside after taking its reference outside.

```
 var a;
    function b(){
        var c = new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
            a=resolve;
        });
        return c;
    }
    b().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    }
    );
    a("hai");
```

Comment: It's basically identical with the other answer.