# Handle input events, queue them up, and call async function one by one

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have the following code:

```
database.ref('chats/').on('child_added',(snapshot) => {
  this.addMessage(snapshot.val());
})
```

I get message events when the server database is updated. Then I need to How can I make sure addMessage is not called in parallel?

Comment: Does `.addMessage()` call return a value?

Comment: I can implement addMessage to return a promise if needed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859275/make-a-jquery-function-wait-till-its-previous-call-has-been-resolved/ . Composed a version without using jQuery some time ago; have to locate.

Answer (score 0):

You can push `Promise` or function which return `Promise` to an array. If current `Promise` or function which returns `Promise` is not defined, call first function in array queue, chain `.then()` to schedule call to same function when current asynchronous operation completes, where next item in queue is next item in array, else call function when queue array `.length` is `0`.

```js
window.onload = () => {

  const [queue, input, div] = [
    Array()
  , document.querySelector("input")
  , document.querySelector("div")
  ];
  
  let curr;

  const complete = message => {
    curr = void 0;
    console.log(`message: ${message}, queue.length: ${queue.length}`);
  };

  const processData = data => div.innerHTML += data;

  const checkQueue = (message = "done") =>  
    curr() // `curr()` if pass function to `queue`, `curr` if pass `Promise`
    .then(processData)
    .then(() => (curr = queue.shift()) ? checkQueue(message) : message)   

  const handleMessage = value => {
    queue.push(
      // push function to call that returns `Promise`
      // or push `Promise`, remove `() =>`,
      // include `()` after `curr` at `checkQueue`
      () => new Promise(resolve => 
              setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(value);
              }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500))
            )
    );
    if (!curr) {
      curr = queue.shift();
      checkQueue("complete")
      // do stuff when `queue` `.length` is `0`
      .then(complete);
    }
  }

  input.oninput = () => {
    console.log(input.value.slice(-1));
    handleMessage(input.value.slice(-1));
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<div></div>
```

Where `this.addMessage()` returns `Promise` or a function which returns a `Promise`

```
database.ref('chats/').on('child_added',(snapshot) => {
  handleMessage(this.addMessage(snapshot.val()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution thanks to your input:

```
    var queue = Promise.resolve();
    database.ref('chats/' + this.props.alarm.date).on('child_added',
    (snapshot) => {
      queue =  queue.then(()=> {
        this.addMessage(snapshot.val());
      });
    });
```